# Windows Store App drawing a "smooth" line with Shaped.Line

Tags: c#, xaml, drawing, windows-store-apps, line

I'm currently developing a Windows Store App with C# and Xaml.

I want to draw a diagonal line. For this I'm using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Line`. My problem is, that the line doesn't look 'smooth'.

Is there a better way to do that?